# Can I have multiple transitions on the same property?

Tags: html, css

I need to change width of the element on two different events and with different speeds. Can I somehow specify two transitions of the same property or do I have to change approach?

Let's say I want to quickly increase width of a box with hover. And be able to do the same thing with a button but slower. The problem here is when the class is removed from the box so is the 3s transition. I want a 3s transition to last for the shrinking of the box after the button is pushed again.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");

function growQuickly(){
box.classList.toggle("grow");
}
```

```css
.box{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background: red;
transition: .5s;

}

.box.grow{
width: 200px;
transition: 3s;
}

.box:hover{
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box" ></div>
<button onclick="growQuickly()">GROW SLOWLY</button>
```

Comment: different classes?? hard to know what you mean. Some code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate your logic into more classes and check if something is already included using js.

### CSS

```
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
    width: 200px;
}

.wide {
  width: 200px;
}

.slow {
  transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

### JS

```
const box = document.getElementById('box');

function growQuickly() {
    const boxWidth = box.offsetWidth;
    if (boxWidth === 200 && box.classList.contains('slow')) {
      box.classList.toggle('wide');
      setTimeout(() => box.classList.toggle('slow'), box.style.transitionDuration);
    } else {
      box.classList.toggle('wide');
      box.classList.toggle('slow');
    }
}
```